404 error occurs when requesting file upload of a project deployed to GCP VM (GCP, Spring project)
We are currently working on a Spring Legacy project and implementing a file upload function.
In the local environment, file upload requests using AJAX work normally.
However, when deployed to a VM environment, the browser console experiences a 404 error and the Tomcat log does not log any relevant requests.
The path of the deployed VM is set to ROOT.
Spring Controller Code:
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadajaxAction.do")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<AttachFileVO>> uploadAjaxPost(MultipartFile[] uploadFile) {
    List<AttachFileVO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String uploadfolderPath = getFolder();

    File uploadPath = new File(uploadFolder + "/" + uploadfolderPath);
    if (!uploadPath.exists()) {
        uploadPath.mkdirs();
    }

    for (MultipartFile multipartFile : uploadFile) {
        if (!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
            String uploadFileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            uploadFileName = uploadFileName.substring(uploadFileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);

            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            uploadFileName = uuid.toString() + "_" + uploadFileName;

            try {
                File saveFile = new File(uploadPath, uploadFileName);
                multipartFile.transferTo(saveFile);

                AttachFileVO attachVO = new AttachFileVO();
                attachVO.setUuid(uuid.toString());
                attachVO.setFileName(uploadFileName);
                attachVO.setUploadPath(uploadfolderPath);

                if (checkImageType(saveFile)) {
                    File thumbnailFile = new File(uploadPath, "s_" + uploadFileName);
                    Thumbnails.of(multipartFile.getInputStream())
                            .forceSize(300, 300)
                            .toFile(thumbnailFile);
                    attachVO.setImage(true);
                }

                list.add(attachVO);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}


ajax code
$("input[type='file']").change(function (e) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var inputFile = $("input[name='uploadFile']");
    var files = inputFile[0].files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (!checkExtension(files[i].name, files[i].size)) {
            return false;
        }
        formData.append("uploadFile", files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploadajaxAction.do',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            showUploadResult(result);
        }
    });
});

function checkExtension(fileName, fileSize) {
    var allowedExtensions = /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i;
    var maxSize = 5242880; // 5MB

    if (fileSize >= maxSize) {
        alert("5MB 이하 사이즈의 이미지를 올려주세요.");
        return false;
    }
    if (!allowedExtensions.test(fileName)) {
        alert("이미지 파일(png, jpg, jpeg, gif)만 업로드할 수 있습니다.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


HTML CODE
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label for="datec" class="form-label">대표 이미지</label>
        <div class="uploadDiv">
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" name="uploadFile">
        </div>
        <div class="uploadResult mt-3">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


What I've tried:
View AJAX requests in the browser developer tool:
Request URL: http://vm-address/uploadajaxAction.do
Response Status: 404 Not Found
Check Tomcat Logs:
No request logs are logged in Catalina.out.
Presumably Tomcat is not receiving requests.
VM Environment Check:
The project is distributed to Tomcat's ROOT path.
Static file path and write permissions are set correctly.
How can I debug the cause of the 404 error in the AJAX request?
Why do I experience problems in a VM deployment environment even though it works well locally?
How can I check the possibility that requests like /uploadajaxAction.do will not be forwarded to the controller in a Spring Legacy + Tomcat environment?
